# Why does simplejson think this string is invalid json?

Tags: python, simplejson

I'm trying to convert a simple JSON string `{\n    100: {"a": "b"}\n}` to a python object but its giving me this error: `Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes`

Why is it insisting that the name of the attribute be a string?

```
>>> import simplejson
>>> my_json = simplejson.loads('{\n    100: {"a": "b"}\n}')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/myuser/myenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/simplejson/__init__.py", line 525, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/Users/myuser/myenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/simplejson/decoder.py", line 370, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s)
  File "/Users/myuser/myenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/simplejson/decoder.py", line 400, in raw_decode
    return self.scan_once(s, idx=_w(s, idx).end())
simplejson.errors.JSONDecodeError: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 2 column 5 (char 6)
```

Comment: ...because that's part of the JSON format specification? "A name is a string.", from section 6 of https://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-404.pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This value is invalid `{100: {"a": "b"}}`, you need `{"100": {"a": "b"}}`.

The property name there being `100` needs to be enclosed in double quotes so `"100"`.

> Why is it insisting that the name of the attribute be a string?

That's how JSON is.

You may have been used to be able to write `{100: {"a": "b"}}` in Javascript or another language, (without double quoting the property name), but you'll still get a parsing error if you try to parse it as JSON in Javascript, e.g.:

```
JSON.parse('{100: {"a": "b"}}')
SyntaxError: JSON.parse: expected property name or '}'
at line 1 column 2 of the JSON data
```